# Horizontal line in the middle (text alignment)

Tags: rules, inline

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
y=3x-6 --- {1}\\
y=-x+5 --- {2}\\
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Picture:
[image]

How do I join the three dashes?

I tried `\rule` and `\line` but they only give me a line aligned to the bottom of the text.

Comment: A simple solution is to put `---` in an `\mbox{---}` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
y=3x-6 \mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{2cm}{1pt}}}} {1}\\
y=-x+5 \mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{2cm}{1pt}}}} {2}\\
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on how long the rule should be, you may change the dimension or simply use `\text{---}`..